# Check digital signatures on Word document

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an Excel document listing each Word document that must be send to our customers. These documents must be digitally signed before being sent and I've to check that every document is signed, thanks to VBA via the Excel document. I've found the Signature class and I'm able to have a Signature collection thanks to SignatureSet. But after that I'm lost, I'm only able to know how many signatures are present thanks to this part of code :

```
Set sigs = WordDoc.Signatures
MsgBox (sigs.Count)
```

But what I want is to have the name of each signatory to know who didn't sign the document. I saw that other classes as SignatureInfo or SignatureSetup exist but I can't figure how to use them.

I've already tried the ShowDetails method of the Signature class but it's not what I need because it opens a pop-up in the Word document.

Comment: Have you tried the sample code from the excel help file? Because theres a Popup in there which has nothing to do with the .ShowDetails-method (; `If objSignature.IsSigned then
   Msgbox(The document has been signed with the following details: " & objSignature.ShowDetails) 
Else` Try it without the Msgbox()

Comment: I tried it with and without the MsgBox() and the results are the same, i don't have any details. With the MsgBox() it displays : "The document has been signed with the following details: " and nothing more. When I try to write the content of the ShowDetails method in a range of my Excel file it doesn't write anything neither. Moreover, the Word pop-up is still present, no matter the MsgBox().

Comment: I found this, but no corresponding vba code. https://books.google.de/books?id=4RSAHLMb2DYC&pg=PA345&lpg=PA345&dq=%22who+has+signed%22+a+word+document&source=bl&ots=f-6CPPDcf2&sig=5e_cHO5DnPUgVl9kwR08BIL2RNE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CFkQ6AEwB2oVChMI-9jh64fdxwIVBrYUCh2kaAKr#v=onepage&q=%22who%20has%20signed%22%20a%20word%20document&f=false

Comment: The "Checking a digital certificate" part of the link you posted explain how to "manually" do what the ShowDetails method do. What I'm looking for is, without any pop-up, know who signed the document, looking at each signature present in the document. I'm pretty sure that a method of one of the Signature class can do this job but i can't figure how to do and which of them I've to use. I think that I should use the SuggestedSigner method (Gets or sets the name of the principle signer of the document.) from the SignatureSetup  class but i don't know how to instantiate a SignatureSetup object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has this problem one day, I post here the solution.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim AppWord As Word.Application
    Dim Doc As Word.Document
    Dim Info As SignatureInfo

    Set AppWord = New Word.Application
    AppWord.Visible = True

    Set Doc = AppWord.Documents.Open("C:\MonDocument.doc")

    Set Info = Doc.Signatures(1).Details

    MsgBox Info.SignatureText

End Sub
```